# Invoke AWS Lambda function that is Written in Django App

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron, django-rest-framework, aws-lambda

I have written some cronjobs in my django app and I want to schedule these jobs using AWS Lambda service. Can someone please recommend a good approach to get this done?

Comment: What do you mean with you want to schedule these jobs? If they're cronjobs they should already be scheduled to run some point in the future.

Comment: There are multiple scripts to send the push notifications to users based on some events like if new idea is available, notify the users or if quiz is available, notify the selective users.

I want to write a lambda function that runs once a day and check if new idea is available. If yes, then it runs that particular cronjob.

Comment: What I want is that my lambda function directly check the data from RDS (postgres) and notify users. Since I have already wrote that code in my django app, I just want it to be triggered by lambda function. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check if it is what you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this based on the question's topic rather than the body, since I am not sure what the OP means with "I want to schedule these jobs using AWS Lambda".

If all you want is trigger your Lambda function based in a cronjob, you can use CloudWatch Events to achieve this. You can specify regular cron expressions or some built-in expressions that AWS makes available, like rate(1 min) will run your function every minute. You can see how to trigger a Lambda function via CloudWatch Events on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html). See [cron/rate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) to see all the available options.

CloudWatch Events is only one of the many options to trigger you Lambda function. Your function can react to a whole bunch of AWS Events, including S3, SQS, SNS, API Gateway, etc. You can see the full list of events [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html). Just pick one that fits your needs and you are good to go.

***EDIT AFTER OP'S UPDATE***: 
Yes, what you're looking for is CloudWatch Events. Once you have the Lambda to poll your database in place, you can just create a rule in CloudWatchEvents and have your Lambda be triggered by it. Please see the following images for guidance.

Go to CloudWatch, click on Events and choose Schedule as the Event Source
[image] (make sure to setup your own Cron expression or select the pre-defined rate values)
On the right-hand side, choose your Lambda function accordingly.

Click on "Configure Details" when you are done, give it a name, leave the "Enabled" box checked and finally click on Create.

Go back to your Lambda function and you should see it's now triggered by CloudWatch Events (column on the left-hand side)
[image]

Your lambda is now configured properly and will execute once a day.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.